# if else statement to a comprehension list with enumeration?

Tags: python

Using if-else statements in comprehension lists like this is great:

```
a = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

b = [i-1 if i > 0 else i+1 for i in a]

b
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

also using the enumerations makes possible to use the iterator like:

```
c = [j for j, item in enumerate(b) if item > 0 ]
c
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

but how to add an else statement to a comprehension list with enumeration? i.e. something like

```
c = [j for j, item in enumerate(b) if item > 0 ELSE ]
```

Comment: It's not an `if` statement; it's a conditional expression. You can't use statements of any kind in a list comprehension.

Comment: The condition that's part of the list comprehension syntax does not allow for alternatives using `elif` or `else`; it's just a filter for which elements of `enumerate(b)` to consider.

Comment: the "if" at end filters the data. but at the beginning it conditionanly gives one value or other. So use the first syntax if/else

Comment: Terminology note, that isn't an iterator in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rearrange, such as

```
c = [j if item>0 else 99 for j, item in enumerate(b)]
```

produces

```
[99, 1, 99, 3, 99, 5, 99, 7, 99]
```